# jQuery datatable and Header Checkbox

Tags: jquery, checkbox, datatable

I am using a jQuery Datatable and i would like to have a column of checkboxes and the header should contain a select all checkbox . I have not found any details about this on the datatable official site.

Can someone help?

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Do you have some examples of code you've tried?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way would be to use the aoColumns property of datatables and just render your markup for the "sTitle" property as an html string.

http://www.datatables.net/usage/columns

```
//On datatable init the options would look something like this
"aoColumns": [{   "sTitle": "<input type='checkbox' id='selectAll'></input>"}]
```

Then you could just wire up a handler to the header checkbox after the datatable is created to check/uncheck all the checkboxes;

So something like:

```
$("#selectAll").toggle(function () { 
       $("checkboxSelector", dataTable.fnGetNodes()).attr("checked", true); }
     , function () { 
         $("checkboxSelector", dataTable.fnGetNodes()).attr("checked", false); 
     }
 );
```

Comment: Cdlong, can you explain this code a bit more  ? That would be of great help.

Answer (score 0):

you can have row like below

```
<tr>
<th><input type="checkbox" id="selectall"/></th>
<th>Cell phone</th>
<th>Rating</th>
```

and jquery to wire up

```
<SCRIPT language="javascript">
$(function(){

// add multiple select / deselect functionality
$("#selectall").click(function () {
      $('.case').attr('checked', this.checked);
});

// if all checkbox are selected, check the selectall checkbox
// and viceversa
$(".case").click(function(){

    if($(".case").length == $(".case:checked").length) {
        $("#selectall").attr("checked", "checked");
    } else {
        $("#selectall").removeAttr("checked");
    }

    });
   });
  </SCRIPT>
```

Comment: How about getting all records after clicking to this textbox?